# Passing a array to JavaScript shows as Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a multi dimentional array called `dataArray` like below. it may have indexes 0,1,2,3 without a limit.

I am using codeigniter framework. `dataArray` is all data of a table in the database returned using a model.

```
0:
status: "1"
added_by: "1"
added_on: "2018-12-12 07:01:23"
approved: 0
c _id: "4"
```

I pass this array by onclick function when adding datatable rows as below. (in a foreach)

```
$('#table').DataTable().row.add([
    x, //counter 
    data[j]['action'], //data in foreach
    data[j]['status_1'],
    data[j]['description'],
    data[j]['timestamp'],
    '<input type="button" value="..." onclick="openModal(\'' + dataArray + '\')">' // this is passing array
]).draw(false);
```

`openModal` function is like below.

```
function openModal(data_array){
    console.log(data_array); 
}
```

above console.log returns only `[object Object]`. I want to get data and add a foreach here. But data is not showing. Please help on this.

Comment: Would be good to see where `dataArray` is getting generated.

Comment: A wild guess would be to pass `dataArray.data` but we need to see the where is that variable being filled.

Comment: @fixatd I am using codeigniter framework. dataArray is return by database using model.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I am using codeigniter framework. dataArray is return by database using model.

Comment: @tenten What I mean is how it gets generated in your javascript code rather than the server side code.

Comment: You didn't get what I meant. You're showing us a a variable in your code but you where is it initialized in your javascript? I only see a data[] array, but no dataArray variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to stringify the argument first

```
"<input type='button' value='foo' onclick='openModal(\"" + JSON.stringify(arr) + "\")'>";
```

and then parse on the calling function

```
function openModal(data_array){
    console.log(JSON.parse(data_array)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use JSON.stringify/parse to pass the array data.

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
        var arr = [1,2,3];           

        function openModal(x) {
            x = JSON.parse(x);
            console.log(x);
        }

        document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML+="<input type='button' value='foo' onclick='openModal(\""+JSON.stringify(arr)+"\")'>";       
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add object instead array to DataTable Row.

`$('#table').DataTable().row.add({
    x, //counter 
    data[j]['action'], //data in foreach
    data[j]['status_1'],
    data[j]['description'],
    data[j]['timestamp'],
    '<input type="button" value="..." onclick="openModal(\'' + dataArray + '\')">' // this is passing array}).draw(false);`

Second, 
Console.log(data_array) always show object, u can use Console.log(JSON.stringify(data_array)), or if u want show item one by one, u can use for or jQuery.each